# How can I get the total of records using awk - Solaris

Tags: solaris, services

I'm creating a script to add multiple features to monitor many servers, and I want to add a custom output using echo command to show the total of records as result of the command that I have executed.

The purpose is to show the total number of services that are disabled, enabled, etc.

I used the command in the image, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I need to get the result of 142.

Error:

[image]

Comment: So you want the number of lines in a file. Why not use `wc -l`?

Comment: Thanks. It work as well too. ***`svcs | grep online | wc -l`***

Comment: svcs | grep -c online, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed and simplicity, I would pipe the command output into `wc -l` as Munir suggests. If you really want to use `awk`, just print the number of records in the `END` block:

```
awk 'END { print NR }'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as well.

I actually use:

***svcs | grep disable | awk 'END {print NR}'***